# Return count of relationships instead of all

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I wonder if anyone can advise how to adjust the following query so that it returns one relationship with a count of the number of actual relationships rather than every relationship? I have some nodes with many relationships and it's killing the graph's performance.

```
MATCH (p:Provider{countorig: "XXXX"})-[r:supplied]-(i:Importer)
RETURN p,  i limit 100
```

[image: Image of node with many relationships]

Many thanks

Comment: You can consider refactor the graph so a these connections will be one connection with a `count` property. The question is what other data you have on all these connections and can it be reduced?

Comment: Interesting idea. Thanks. I will play around with that approach

Answer (score 0):

To return the relationship name along with a count, change your "return" statement, like this:

```
MATCH (p:Provider{countorig: "XXXX"})-[r:supplied]-(i:Importer)
RETURN type(r), count(r)
```

Using `type(r)` will return the type of the relationship, which looks to be "supplied" in your example. And then `count(r)` is just using the built-in function to count the number of occurrences of that relationship in the query.